# UWP custom control with overflow layout

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

In default maps application there are control, that overflows other content on page. It's height can be changed by sliding up and sliding down this layout.
Is there way to implement that control?

P.S. sorry for my english

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you 100% sure it overlaps with a page content? This looks like a regular splitter for me...

Comment: I think it overlaps page content because map control height doesn't change. When map height/width changes, map reloads tiles. You can see it in uwp applications with maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `Grid` or `Canvas` control you can overlay controls.

If you used a `Grid` control you would put all elements on the same `Grid.Row` but the order they appear in the XAML would determine their Z-Index. The control you want at the bottom could then be placed by setting the `VerticalAlignment` to `Bottom`.